# Error boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular in lme4 Model

Tags: r, regression, lme4

I have the following structure:

```
'data.frame':   1041 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ RST_AST: num  0.45 0.576 0.45 0.45 0.675 ...
 $ subj   : chr  "4" "13" "24" "25" ...
 $ domain : chr  "perceptual" "perceptual" "perceptual" "perceptual" ...
 $ ce     : chr  "compromise" "compromise" "compromise" "compromise" ...
```

Now I want to run a Multilevel Model using lme4 package like these:

```
library(lme4) #load package

ce_model <- lmer(RST_AST ~ domain + ce+ (1|subj), data = df_RST_AST)
```

Then I get the error message:

```
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

I have no clue what's wrong?

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you read `?isSingular` ... ?

Comment: Without data it is impossible to be sure but the usual reason for this is that there is so little variation in the random intercepts that the software cannot detect it.

Comment: @BenBolker It might be helpful to change that to `help("isSingular")`. I have doubts that most RStudio users are familiar with the `?` operator.

Comment: @Roland, good point.

Comment: Can you provide any more detail or explain more about where you got stuck?  See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378939/dealing-with-singular-fit-in-mixed-models ;  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/450162/how-to-solve-the-error-of-singular-fit-in-glmm-in-r ; https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444418/singular-fit-with-simplest-random-structure-in-glmer-lme4 ; https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-models-random-effect-variances-estimated-as-zero-or-correlations-estimated-as---1 ...

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that one of your variables is not being evaluated as contributing to the variance. Most likely, the "culprit" is the random variable (subj in your case). If you look at the output of your model (just print ce_model and hit enter, or summary(ce_model)), there should be a variable that has zero or very nearly zero variance and standard deviation. There are several ways to deal with this (see any of the links above). I would recommend analyzing the faulty variable, what kind of distribution does it have, can it be transformed, ...etc. Perhaps you need to do one or more generalized models with the data. It might also be helpful to look at your model or models; however, without further info it is hard to tell.